# How to set cooling fans speed using IPMI?

Tags: ipmi, fan

I have a NEC server.
Model Express5800/T120d [N8100-1957F]
Chipset Intel C602

This server has very loud fans: I hear them at the next floor, all doors closed.
I can read cooling fans speed, but I found no way to change it.

Nothing into the BIOS to change fan speed, Linux detect nothing valuable into /sys/class/hwmon/ (no pwm entries), lmsensors find nothing, no Windows driver, and no Windows utility found anything.

The fans are PWM. I tested them into another computer and I can do whatever I want with the speed. For example using `echo  50  > /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/pwm1`

The NEC motherboard has the ability to change fans speed because the speed change during different phases of boot.

I hope I can drive the fans using IPMI.

IPMI allow to get fans informations:
`ipmitool sdr` and `ipmitool sensor`:

```
[...]
FAN1             | 8210.18 RPM       | ok
FAN2             | 933.71 RPM        | nc
FAN3             | 933.71 RPM        | nc
FAN4             | no reading        | ns
[...]
```

`ipmitool sdr get FAN1` and `ipmitool sensor get FAN1`:

```
Sensor ID              : FAN1 (0x50)
Entity ID             : 7.1 (System Board)
Sensor Type (Threshold)  : Fan (0x04)
Sensor Reading        : 8210.181 (+/- inf) RPM
Status                : ok
Nominal Reading       : 2532.928
Normal Minimum        : 2976.190
Normal Maximum        : 1392.370
Upper non-critical    : 960.061
Positive Hysteresis   : 238095.238
Negative Hysteresis   : Unspecified
Minimum sensor range  : 238095.238
Maximum sensor range  : Unspecified
Event Message Control : Entire Sensor Only
Readable Thresholds   : unc
Settable Thresholds   : unc
Threshold Read Mask   : unc
Assertion Events      :
Assertions Enabled    : unc+
Deassertions Enabled  : unc+
```

Reading is ok, but I don't know how to use IPMI to change fans speed.
I found some people doing it with a Dell server:

```
# manual fan control
ipmitool raw "0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00"
# set fan level
ipmitool raw "0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff " + hex(fan_level)
```

But I don't know how to find the correct values for my NEC server.

--> the question is: how can I modify cooling fans speed using IPMI for my NEC server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control fans on a NEC server under Linux? With IPMI or BMC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/980124/how-to-control-fans-on-a-nec-server-under-linux-with-ipmi-or-bmc)

Comment: suggested answer is not an answer for this question (this question is about IPMI): author of suggested answer wrote: "I don't know how to use IPMI from command line, so I don't know if it is possible to change fan speed"